# How to ensure onStop() method gets called when phone call is received using Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've got some legacy code I'm working on that is triggered in `onStop()` method for my activity. When I put the app in the background using the home button, the `onPause()` followed by the `onStop()` methods are triggered in both non-lollipop and lollipop devices, and I get to clean up my activity. On non-lollipop devices when I receive a phone call, the `onPause()` - `onStop()` methods are called, and I get to clean-up my activity as expected. However, using lollipop, only the `onPause()` method is called when the phone call is received and accepted.

Has anyone else seen this, and have a work-around to this situation? Thanks.

Comment: can you use onPause only for the cleanup?

Comment: how are you determining that onStop is not being called?

Comment: I'm using break points in onPause() and onStop() methods of my activity.  The onStop() break point isn't being reached.

Comment: This is happening because phone calls in Lollipop are shown using a high priority notification that overlays your content (rather than opening a full-screen activity). In this case, since your Activity is still visible, but in the background, it is PAUSED, but not STOPPED. This avoids having your activity interrupted when a phone call comes in. I'm not sure why this is bad for your app, but it seems like you should let your app continue even when the call notification appears (since the user may not care, and just dismiss the call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a `BroadCastReciever` for a Incoming call intent and do it in `onRecieveIntent` . Only a workaround though but will do the trick in all cases and all os versions.

Comment: This sounds like it may be the way to go, I'll test it out. Thanks.

Comment: Wanted to test out your suggestion before I marked it.  Again, thanks for your answer.

Comment: No probs buddy happy coding :)